# EC2 InvalidRegionError when using ConnetionBorg.set_region('us-east-2')

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I ssh into ec2 instance and run the following:

```
conn = ConnectionBorg()
conn.set_credentials("------------A", "---------")
conn.set_region('us-east-2')
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
```

in response I get:

> raise InvalidRegionError("Region name %s is invalid" % region_name)
>   dynamodb_mapper.model.InvalidRegionError: Region name us-east-2 is invalid

if I run it with us-east-1 instead, it doesn't throw an InvalidRegionError but of course us-east-1 is not my region.

If I run:

```
$ REGION=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|grep region|awk -F\" '{print $4}'`
```

Then

```
echo $REGION
us-east-2
```

Also, my aws version isn't old. I've updated that.

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.160 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.9.38-16.35.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.7.18
```

Any ideas to resolve this? thanks.

Comment: `aws --version` is just showing you the version of the AWS CLI tool you have installed. You need to check the version of boto3 you are using in your Python script.

Comment: I updated my install of boto3. Now it's working. Thank you very much.

Comment: What permissions does the IAM user have? Also running applications on EC2, best practice is to use an IAM role/instance profile instead of keys. Also what version of dynamodb_mapper are you using?